# Добавление политики конфиденциальности в приложение в Google Play Market

Tags: google-play, privacy

На днях пришло письмо от команды Google с таким содержанием: Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. Когда я захожу в консоль разработчика там нужно указать ссылку на политику конфиденциальности. Вопрос заключается в следующем - где ее вобще взять? Ее как то получать специально надо?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для публикации политики конфиденциальности не имея собственного сайта или домена необходимо сделать следующее:

> 1. Создание статического веб-сайта. Одним из вариантов является [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).
> 2. Создайте документ, описывающий, как вы планируете использовать необходимые разрешения.
> 3. Добавьте документ на вебсайт.
> 4. Добавьте ссылку на этот документ в Developer Console.
> 5. Добавьте ссылку на этот документ в ваше приложение.