# Google Drive вместо сервера для приложения

Tags: android, сервер, rest, хранение-данных, google-drive

Пишу приложение на Android.Есть необходимость в хранении данных, к которым пользователь будет получать доступ. Данные будут добавляться \ удаляться каждый день (изображения, текстовые файлы). Рассматривал Google Drive, но есть пару моментов:

1) для доступа через API пользователю приложения необходимо выполнять вход в Google аккаунт. Хотелось бы, чтобы доступ на просмотр\скачивание файлов был без авторизации.
2)При регистрации окна доступа OAuth требуются ссылки на сайт приложения и политику конфиденциальности, которых нет. Насколько я понял, без данной проверки пользователь будет видеть только файлы и папки созданные им самим через данное приложение. Мне же требуется все с точности наоборот - чтобы он мог только читать данные созданные мной.

Посоветуйте как лучше организовать этот момент? С помощью Google Drive или лучше использовать другой сервис (лучше бесплатный).

Comment: данные будут общедоступные или относящиеся только к одному пользователю?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko данные одни для всех пользователей

Comment: По прямым ссылкам можно качать общедоступные файлы с диска без регистрации, авторизации и API. Вопрос только откуда брать сами ссылки? Посмотрите есть ли возможность изменить содержимое файла так, чтобы ссылка на него не изменилась. Тогда такую ссылку можно зашить в приложение и по ней скачивать, как минимум, текстовый файл со ссылками на остальной контент.

Comment: @woesss прямую ссылку могу разместить только на папку с диска. В данную папку будут добавляться каждый день другие с контентом в виде пары картинок и тексового файла. Т.е. надо будет парсить содержимое корневой папки в список объектов (каждая подпапка = объект с инфой).

Comment: Видно мы друг друга не поняли... Я предположил идти в обход API, генерировать инфу о папках в файл, качать и парсить этот файл в приложении. Ладно, если проблема в пункте 2 - что если написать заявление о конфиденциальности в файл на том же диске и дать ссылку на его страницу? Или так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629104/11515 .Пункт 1 не знаю точно как победить, но каждое устройство обязано иметь гугло-аккаунт для доступа к маркету - и что-то смутно припоминается о возможности авторизоваться через этот аккаунт.При этом юзеру предлагается только дать разрешение, а не вводить логин/пароль.

Comment: И что-то мне кажется, что логин юзера и политика нужны для доступа к его личному диску, а не к вашему - почитайте их доки повнимательней.